# WPF MVVM-Light how to use the passed DragEventArgs through relay command to view model in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am working in WPF Project where there is a combobox control where user want to drag and drop object.
When user drag object on top of the control, it does not allow drop (Not allowed mouse cursor)
I know by adding the drag over function, it may allow dropping but I am working in MVVM design pattern.
Is there anyway to bind relay command to view model.
i.e.

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragOver">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct xaml namespace added:

`xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"`

Then add the handler to your combobox like so:

```xml
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragOver">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DragOverCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```